# How to total table based on specific column or index with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like blow code:

```
<table class="somting">
  <tr>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>Item</th>
     <th>Item Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Car</td>
     <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Book</td>
     <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>Pen</td>
     <td>100</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Now my problem is that how can I get the sub total of Item costs column
with jquery

I mean how to add 200+500+100

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: I don't know that is why I asked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
sum=0;
$('.somting td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
   sum += parseInt($(this).text());
})
//log sum
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vodjfgrh/)**

Comment: Thinks but when I run It gives NaN I don't know why

Comment: @MehdiJalal: works fine in fiddle. can you reproduce the problem in fiddle??

Answer (score 0):

You add a class to item code row like

```
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Car</td>
     <td class="price">200</td>
  </tr>
```

and then use

```
var total = 0;
$(".price").each(function(){
    total += parseFloat( $(this).html());
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/8wqppuo6

Comment: how to add those classes to those columns using jQuery because I can't the table is dynamically generated

Comment: Or is there any way to total it based on index or column position

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="somting">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Item Cost</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Car</td>
        <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Book</td>
        <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Pen</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $("table.somting");
        var tds = table.find("tr td:nth-child(3)");

        var sum = 0;

        $.each(tds, function(i, me){
            var val = parseFloat($(me).text());
            sum += val;
        });

        var append = '<tr><td></td><td></td><td class="price"> '+sum+'</td></tr>';

        table.append(append);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tot = 0;
$('table.somting tr').each(function(index, elem) {
    p = $(this).find(":nth-child(3)").html();
    p = parseInt(p);        
    if (!isNaN(p)) {          
      tot = tot + p;
    }               
});
console.log(tot);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sum =0;
$('table tr:not(:first)').each(function() {
  var lasttd=  $(this).find(':last-child')
   sum+=parseInt(lasttd.text());
});
alert(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="somting">
  <tr>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>Item</th>
     <th>Item Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Car</td>
     <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Book</td>
     <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>Pen</td>
     <td>100</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $("table.somting");
        var tds = table.find("tr td:nth-child(3)");
        var sum = 0;
            $.each(tds, function(i, me){
                var val = parseFloat($(me).text());
                sum += val;
            });
        var append = '<tr><td></td><td></td><td class="price"> '+sum+'</td></tr>';
        table.append(append);

    });

</script>
```